# Laravel 5 - Validate Multiple Request

Tags: php, validation, request, laravel-5

is it possible, in Laravel 5, to validate multiple Requests in order to insert related models after a form submission?
I know how to validate multiple Model by using Validators but I want to do it with the Request Class.

### Laravel 4 :

```
$validateUser = Validator::make(Input::all(), User::$rules);
$validateRole = Validator::make(Input::all(), Role::$rules);

if ($validateUser->fails() || $validateRole->fails()){
    $validationMessages = array_merge_recursive(
        $validateUser->messages()->toArray(),
        $validateRole->messages()->toArray()
    );
}
```

### Laravel 5 :

Request one

```
class CreateUserRequest extends Request {

    public function rules()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Request two

```
class CreateRoleRequest extends Request {

    public function rules()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Controller Model call :

```
public function store(CreateUserRequest $request, CreateRoleRequest $request2)
{
    //
}
```

How can I validate the User input values and the Role input values using the Request approach?
(and have a specific feedback if validation fails)

Comment: For sure I did. And as espected it doesnt work at all. I think we can't use 2 Request as parameter. Every input fields are attached to the first Request parameter.

Comment: Doesn't work means only one request is validated?

Comment: Exactly. I think i can validate everything in one Request but I want to do it in a cleaner way by separating the validation.

Comment: I just tried it and it actually worked with type hinting two request classes. (both `validate()` methods were called). I suppose in your real code you don't have the `CreateUserRequest` and `UserRequest` discrepancy?

Comment: Oh, yes sorry just edited. Can i see how you manage everything ? Like what do you have in your form, what do you have in your Requests and what do you have in your controller. A working example or i don't know. How does your Request know what input it has to check and what it hasn't?

Comment: I only tested if `validate()` is called on both form requests. Maybe I'll do some more testing and show you my code later...

Comment: Many thanks Lukas, I can't wait for that.

Comment: Okay, you were right. It actually works.

Comment: Haha yay!! What was the problem?

Comment: I had two input with the same name : like user.name and role.name. So I never saw the second request working. (I had to rename the column in my DB, no other option ?)  If you can provide a simple answer so I can mark it as resolved. Again, thank you very much Lukas !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, using multiple form request classes works perfectly fine.

---

Now of course you can't just have two forms in one. However what you can do to separate your data, is to use the array syntax for field names:

```
<input type="text" name="user[name]" />
<!-- and later -->
<input type="text" name="role[name]" />
```

In your validation rules you can then use the dot syntax to reference either the user name or the role name:

```
public function rules(){
    return [
        'role.name' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

And for creating the two models, just use this to get all the attributes for `user` and `role`:

```
$request->input('user'); // returns an array like ['name' => 'foo', 'other-user-field' => 'bar']
$request->input('role'); // returns an array like ['name' => 'baz', 'other-role-field' => 'boom']
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I change displayed name in attributes in `lang/en/validation.php`. When the name was just `user` I could add `'name' => 'Name',` but with arrays I can't figure out what to do. `'role.name' => 'Name'` does not work

Comment: I believe you can just add a nested array. So it would be `'role' => [ 'name' => 'Name' ]`

Comment: That did it. Also one more question. When I do validation in `public function rules(MyRequest $request, SecondRequest $request){ ... }` is it possible to triger both Requests at the same time? Now if validation don't pass in both Requests I only get errors for the first one: `MyRequest`, and `SecondRequest` only triggers after `MyRequest` passes.

Comment: @dbr I don't think that's possible. If you need more help, please ask a new question.