# Laravel 5 - Validate Multiple Request - do all Requests at the same time

Tags: php, validation, request, laravel-5.1

Continuing discussion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443280/laravel-5-validate-multiple-request)

If we have two Requests like:

`public function store(FirstRequest $request, SecondRequest $request)
    { ... }`

is it possible to run both Requests and not one after another. This way if validation doesn't pass for FirstRequest, SecondRequest won't start and it will create error messages only after FirstRequest passes without any errors.

Comment: for laravel 5.5 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48370879/laravel-5-5-validate-multiple-form-request-at-the-same-time/48371383#48371383

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can "manually creating validators"

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#other-validation-approaches

Basically in your method instead of use a a Request injection, use the rules directly in the method and call the $validator->fails() method for every set of rules.

Something like this:

```
public function store(Request $request){

    $rulesFirstRequest = ['field1' => 'required', 'field2' => 'required'];
    $rulesSecondRequest = ['field12' => 'required', 'field22' => 'required'];

    $validator1 = Validator::make($request->all(), $rulesFirstRequest);
    $validator2 = Validator::make($request->all(), $rulesSecondRequest);

    if ($validator1->fails() && $validator2->fails()) {
      //Do stuff and return with errors
   }
   // return with success
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This is a valid workaround but not what I hoped for. Though, as @lukasgeiter noted, it's possible that it can't be done using Requests. I'll upvote it but leave as unanswered for now.