# How to adapt Laravel controller code to follow DRY principle when there is overlap between assumptions?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My aim is to adapt the following controller methods to follow the DRY principle by moving the validation to form requests. However, I have a problem which is that there are overlaps between validation for different methods. For example, let's say that the input form has only one field and that's `name`, and that it's related to a `Task` model. Let's consider 3 controller methods now:

- `store` method: validate that `name` isn't empty
- `update` method: validate that `name` isn't empty and that a `Task` with the given `$id` exists
- `destroy` method: validate that a `Task` with the given `$id` exists

So for the `store` method I am checking the first assumption, for the `destroy` method I am checking the second assumption, and for the `update` method I am checking both.

So, ideally, I would like to be able to do something like...

```
public function store(StoreTask $request)...
public function update(Store Task TaskExists $request, $id)...
public function destroy(TaskExists $id)...
```

...but I am very unclear on how to write the syntax for this, and whether there is some other approach which I'm missing to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: If you use dependency injection with Laravel, you do not need to check if the given id exists. For example, in `update(Request $r, Task $task)`, laravel will automatically check if the task that belongs to the sent id (or task) exists. So you can have a shared validation logic that applies `required` rule on `name`. Maybe do it through request, or have a separate function..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Validation:**

With [Route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-model-binding) Laravel will automatically inject the model instance so you don't have to query the database yourself and if you have the same validation for storing and updating a task you can use the same [form request](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#form-request-validation) for both actions.

So in the end you would have something like this:

```
public function store(TaskRequest $request)...
public function update(TaskRequest $request, Task $task)...
public function destroy(Task $task)...
```

If you have different Validation rules for storing and updating, you can create two form requests:

```
public function store(StoreTaskRequest $request)...
public function update(UpdateTaskRequest $request, Task $task)...
```

And then either repeat your validation rules in both requests or use either a trait / separate class or method that contains the rules and merge them when needed.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48370879/laravel-5-5-validate-multiple-form-request-at-the-same-time) has some good suggestions.

**Authorization:**

To check if the user is allowed to edit/update the task I would use [Laravel's Authorization](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization).

In your case you could create a [policy](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization#writing-policies).

In your `TaskPolicy`:

```
public function update(User $user, Task $task)
{
    return $user->id === $task->user_id;
}
```

In your `TaskController`:

Constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->authorizeResource(Task::class, 'task');
}
```

Or single action:

```
public function update(UpdateTaskRequest $request, Task $task)
{
    $this->authorize('update', $task);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, route-model binding does solve the problem for the example I posted. but what if I still have to validate different things, for example in the `update` method I may want to make some additional check, such as that the `task` hasn't been updated in the last 24 hours?

Comment: Or I may want to check in the `update` method that the `task` belongs to the user who is trying to make the update (column `user_id`)...

Comment: Awesome answer, I learned a lot about how Laravel handles this sort of thing.

Comment: One more thing: I'll still need to catch whatever exception the policy throws if the condition is not filled, so I suppose I'll still need a `try...catch` block or something similar in the controller method? Or there is a way for the policy to handle that on its end?

Comment: @jovan The policy will throw a `AuthorizationException` if the user is not authorized and Laravel's error handler will catch it and return a `403` response automatically so you don't need a try catch block.